# SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "onBeforeOpen"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and [Sweetalert v2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and I tried firing this alert with it at the Blade:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: '<h4 style="color: #0c5460;">Updating user status</h4>',
    html: '<h5 style="color: #0c5460">Wait...</h5>',
    width: 400,
    padding: '1em',
    background: '#fff url(/images/cream_pixels.png)',
    timer: 1000,
    onBeforeOpen: () => {
        Swal.showLoading()
    },
});
```

And it popups properly but does not show the loader and shows me this error at the Console:

**SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "onBeforeOpen"**

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: @KenLee Can you explain more about what you say

Comment: @KenLee I have used `onBeforeOpen () {  Swal.showLoading()  },` instead and shows me the same error !!

Comment: @KenLee "realrashid/sweet-alert": "^5.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **didOpen**: Asynchronously runs after the popup has been shown on screen. Provides popup DOM element as the argument

```
              Swal.fire({
                didOpen: () => {
                  Swal.showLoading();
                }
              })
```